# How is the parallel runner running the feature files

Tags: dsl, karate

I have set the following code in my java file:

```
  @CucumberOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
  public class ExamplesTest {

  @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        System.setProperty("karate.env", "dev");
    }

@Test
public void testParallel() {
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath);
    generateReport(karateOutputPath);
    assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);        
}

public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();        
}
}
```

As you can see, i have set the thread count to 1 , but even if i increase it i see no difference in the execution time.

I am not very sure how the parallel run is happening.

Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the unit of parallelization is at the feature file level. This means:

- if you have 1 feature there is no effect
- if you have multiple features but one of them takes a very long time, the test will run for that amount of time

Comment: i have 7 feature files , so does that mean if i put 7 threads then each thread will run each feature file?

Comment: Okay Thanks Peter